# Can't have my child row's element to the right side in my ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I have created an ExpandableListView with the following code:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" /> <!-- This last line fixes a bug with a black background when scrolling through the list -->
```

The xml that defines the parent row is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/childname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, the xml that defines the child row is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/childname"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.80"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/check1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:focusable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to have the CheckBox to the very right of the screen.
During design time, in eclipse, the element is actually to the right. But when I install it in my phone, it is not.

Here is the screenshot of the result: http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/584/97598265.png

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Regards,
Felipe

**UPDATE**
Following recommendation, this is what I did to have it working:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/childname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/check1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:focusable="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relativeLayout for proper alignment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/childname"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
android:layout_weight="0.80"
android:focusable="false"
android:textSize="14sp" />

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/check1"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/childname"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/childname"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_weight="0.2"
android:focusable="false" />
```